# Как сделать редактирование сообщения в inline bot telegram aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, inline

Пытаюсь написать бота с inline-режимом на python с помощью библиотеки aiogram.Который бы отправлял анимационные сообщения. Хочу, чтобы он работал следующим образом.

1. Вызов бота через @ в чат
2. Пользователь выбирает анимацию
3. После нажатия отправляется анимационное сообщение

Хотел сделать анимацию сообщения с помощью редактирование текста, но проблема у InlineQuery нет метода `edit_text`

```
async def inline_echo(inline_query: InlineQuery):
    text = "Начинаем загрузку..."
    input_content = InputTextMessageContent(text)
    item = InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=str(uuid4()),
        title="magic",
        description="description",
        input_message_content=input_content,
        thumb_url="https://clipart-best.com/img/heart/heart-clip-art-233.png",
        thumb_width=10,
        thumb_height=10,
    )

    await bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, results=[item], cache_time=1)
    for i in range(101):
        await text.edit_text(text=f"{i}%")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

**В строчки** `await text.edit_text(text=f"{i}%")` ошибка: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'edit_text'

Comment: Принтани что выдает inline_query

Comment: {"id": "5593044599932091067", "from": {"id": 1302232174, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Danil", "username": "DaMiR_9m", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat_type": "sender", "query": "", "offset": ""}

Comment: В query попадёт текст

Comment: Попробуй вызвать edit_text у query

Comment: Ошибка: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'edit_text'

Comment: Я так понял метод edit text есть только у класса Message

Comment: А какой у тебя декоратор над inline echo?

Comment: @dp.inline_handler()